# i dont recognise the separator used here on my keyboard? |9|1|

Tags: separator

I have strokes between numbers that I don't recognise on my keyboard:-

> |9|1|

I need to be able to say, if "1" is included in the field include in selection, else exclude. For ";" I have used the following formula, but I don't know what the stroke is?

```
SUBSTRING(JobSites,6,CHARINDEX('I',JobSites))
```

Any help appreciated.
Laura

Comment: thankyou Ken.  how do I note that you have answered my question.  I cant see where to say "question answered" by you anywhere on this website?

Comment: I've posted an answer below. You can indicate it's provided a solution by clicking the checkmark at the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The *stroke* is a *vertical line* (Unicode 007C, or Chr(124)), and is commonly referred to as the *pipe* character, as in *pipe-delimited text* such as you have posted here. It's typically produced by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (the shift key + the backslash key) on most US keyboard layouts.

I believe what you're trying to do can be solved using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT <your fields> FROM <your table> WHERE job LIKE '%|1|%`
```

Comment: I've tried using... select where job = '%|1|%' to pick up any field where there exists |1 but it doesn't work.  any suggestions please?
|10|
|1|
|9|1|
|10|1|
I can't use the following formula either as the character length is not consistant  ...SUBSTRING(JobSites,2,CHARINDEX('|',JobSites)) as first

Comment: I accidently pressed enter ken.  I hadn't finished writing.

Comment: @yoda: If your question is about writing SQL, then edit your question and clearly indicate that, and add a tag for both *sql* and the specific database (RDBMS) you're using, include the full SQL statement you're using and make it clear what isn't working for you, and I'll delete this answer. It's certainly not clear from your current question that it's what you're asking.